# France is not the main destination for my trip; could it be a reason of rejection for Schengen visa?

Tags: france, schengen-visas, destinations

I applied for a Schengen visa through TLS contact for France in London.
I gave two different travel plans, one in April 11 days, other one in August 3 days. My first travel plan starts with 3 days in Paris, 3 days in Frankfurt and 5 days in Amsterdam. Second travel plan will be 3 days in Paris in August.

So for this case, the agent told me that France is not the longest stay in your travel plan so it can be too risky to be rejected by the French consulate. I took that risk and submitted my application.

Is there anyone rejected for this reason? If you consider my application it includes two different travel plans and as a result of this, my total days of stay in France will be 6 (3 days in first trip and 3 days for the second). Does this conform to the rule of the longest stay must be the main destination or not?

Comment: You've already submitted your application so nothing we say now will make any difference. You'll have to wait until the application is decided. Good luck!

Comment: The question is not only to solve my problem but also could be a warning or informing people in the same conditions, so if someone has that kind of experience, please share with us for the benefit of the community.

Comment: They would not even decide the application, but return it undecided, since they are not the right consulate to examine it. (This means among other things that you won't have a visa refusal in your history to explain to countries that ask about such things).

Comment: I had the same issue. May I know whether you got your visa?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's also worth noting that if they make that decision they will refund the visa application fee, though I believe the TLS service fee would not be refunded.

Answer (score 2):

It's not up to you to combine the two trips and apply for a single visa for both, what you are supposed to do is to apply for a visa for the first trip from the Dutch consulate and, after your return, go through the French consulate to get another visa for the second trip. As a UK resident, it's also possible that the Dutch consulate would give you a multiple-entry visa anyway. In that case, you could use that visa for the second trip as well.

Technically however, applying to the wrong consulate should not attract a refusal (i.e. a negative decision) but the consulate should decline to process your application and refund the application fee. You might also get lucky and get a multiple-entry visa from the French consulate but the rules are clear and your application does not follow them.

Comment: If the consulate declines to process the application, as I understand it, the applicant will only receive a refund of the visa fee, not of the TLS service charge.

Comment: @phoog In practice, that's definitely the case. I have always wondered whether it should be the case or not.